# How to pass an argument from a function to another one

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react native . My total goal is to pass `passedThis` from `myfunction1` into `chPSCallback`. So, I made `passedThis` value into a public value so that, I can use it in `function2`. Here is my code:

```
var passedThisGlob;

var start1 = {       
    myfunction1: function(ID, passedThis) {
        var callbacks = {
            chPS: this.chPSCallback,
        };
        passedThisGlob = passedThis;
        Mylib.start(ID, callbacks);
    },
    chPSCallback: function(positionState) {
        passedThis.props.navigation.navigate('test', { user: passedThis.state.user });
        alert('Test works!);
    },
}
```

**UPDATE**: I figure out that, the `chPSCallback` executed first.

I need to do the navigation in `chPSCallback` function using `passedThis` so that, I need `passedThis` in it. Can you help me how to do that? Is the global variable solution a good idea?

Comment: you could make it a property of `start`

Comment: @TKoL: For some reason I can not. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Why are are using the start variable. Why not put the two functions separately outside it?

Comment: @Srijith: It is a library that should be start first. And I want to make another library and call it in future.

Comment: @Queen why can't you?

Comment: Sorry, It is a misunderstanding here! the first start was start1. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var start = {       
    myfunction1: function(ID, passedThis) {
        var callbacks = {
            chPS: function(){this.chPSCallback()},
        };
        this._passedThis = passedThis;
        Mylib.start(ID, callbacks);
    },
    chPSCallback: function(positionState) {
        this._passedThis.props.navigation.navigate('test', { user: this._passedThis.state.user });
        alert('Test works!);
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tested that, It gave me red page error and as I omitted the "this._passedThis.props.navigation.navigate('test', { user: this._passedThis.state.user });", it worked!

Comment: The error is not a clear thing, it shows "com.facebook.react.common.javascriptException..."